# How to bring DIV2 to top WRT DIV1?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to bring DIV2 on top of DIV1,I have followed few of the earlier questions but nothing seems to have solved my problem .

Here are the corresponding DIV elemnts folowed by their CSS.

This is what am refering to DIV1

```
 <div class="left_black_out"><img alt=" close" src="./img/slider_in.png" style="background:none rgba(255,255,255,0.8); opacity:.3">
      <div class="world" >
        <h2>WORLD ABOVE THE WORLD</h2>
        <p>THIS IS IN TOP</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is DIV2

```
<div class="disclaimer4" id="basic-modal-content">
  <h3>Disclaimer</h3>
  <p>Want this on TOP</p>
</div>
```

Corresponding CSS

```
.left_black_out {
    background:none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    zoom:1;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    left: -660px;
    top:30px;
    padding: 100px 60px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    z-index: 9990;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    float: left;    
    margin-top:-30px;   
}

.disclaimer4 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .99
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;    
}
```

If I change the  position to "relative" the DIV1 vanishes completely.
I have tried different values for z-index of DIV2 including negative values. 
Still am not able to bring it to top .
How this can be achieved.

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle ?

Comment: why this left: -660px; in div1 is it necessary?

Comment: radha yes it is required in the project

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nihar/pg3af/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
.left_black_out {
    background:none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    zoom:1;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    left: -660px;
    top:30px;
    padding: 100px 60px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    float: left;    
    margin-top:-30px; 
    z-index:0;
}

.disclaimer4 {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left; 
    background:#fff;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0.9;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3WSm/4/

Comment: with this the background image does not load ,i tried putting an image in the js fiddle but its not working either ,
else all fine,but the background image must load

Comment: local src file url ll does not load use live src url to the image in jsfiddle

Comment: I tried with the source file from one of the Google image
am a new comer may be putting the wrong syntax,

u can check this though 

http://jsfiddle.net/Nihar/pg3af/#base

i have put an image link in your js fiddle source

Answer (score 0):

[Your answer: fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ga6fV/)

```
.left_black_out {
background:none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
zoom:1;
bottom: 0;
display: block;
height:100%;
left: -660px;
top:30px;
padding: 100px 60px 30px;
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
z-index: -9990;
float: left;    
margin-top:-30px;
```

}

change the z-index of .left_black_out in minus(-9990;)

[z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: can use please set up fiddle for your question @N.Nihar

Comment: Even the js fiddle has stunned me ,its working fine there but not in the real case 

http://jsfiddle.net/Nihar/pg3af/2/

Comment: Are u able to toggle between the divs 
Changing the Z index value does not try to solve the issue

Comment: give the live url @nihar den only we can proceed its working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/a3WSm/

Comment: u can check this link 

http://www.theimperialedge.in/enquiry.html

in the bottom right u can see "DIsclaimer",click that u can get teh issue